# Threading issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm reading Bruce Eckel's book ["Thinking in C++", vol. 2](http://www.mindviewinc.com/downloads/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-two.zip) and while doing exercise 13 from chapter 11 I've encountered a problem.

Exercise 13: Create two Runnable subclasses, one with a run() that starts and calls wait(). The other class’s run() should capture the reference of the first Runnable object. Its run() should call signal() for the first thread after some number of seconds have passed so that first thread can print a message.

Runnable class is from [ZThreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZThreads) library.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "zthread/Runnable.h"
#include "zthread/Condition.h"
#include "zthread/Mutex.h"
#include "zthread/Guard.h"
#include "zthread/CountedPtr.h"
#include "zthread/Thread.h"

class Class1: public ZThread::Runnable {
    ZThread::Mutex lock;
    ZThread::Condition condition;
public:
    Class1(): condition(lock) {}

    void run() {
        ZThread::Guard<ZThread::Mutex> g(lock);
        std::cout << "Class1::run()\n";
        condition.wait();
        std::cout << "Message\n";
    }

    void continue1() {
        ZThread::Guard<ZThread::Mutex> g(lock);
        std::cout << "Class1::continue1()\n";
        condition.signal();
    }
};

class Class2: public ZThread::Runnable {
    ZThread::CountedPtr<Class1>& c;
public:
    Class2(ZThread::CountedPtr<Class1>& c1): c(c1) {}

    void run() {
        std::cout << "Class2::run()\n";
        ZThread::Thread::sleep(2000);
        std::cout << "Calling continue1()\n";
        c->continue1();
        std::cout << "Exiting Class2::run()\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    ZThread::CountedPtr<Class1> c(new Class1);
    std::cout << "Starting thread 1\n";
    ZThread::Thread t1(c);
    std::cout << "Starting thread 2\n";
    ZThread::Thread t2(new Class2(c));
    std::cout << "exit\n";
}
```

It hangs and doesn't print "Message". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What *does* it print? (and consider using `std::cerr` which doesn't buffer, or better still, make both classes construct to use a target `std::ostream&` member for debug output.) Not having the framework you're using installed (and not about to, at that), doesn't make this any easier.

Comment: I don't know how `ZThread::Guard<ZThread::Mutex>` works, but you are holding onto it in both threads at once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program ends with function main and both threads are interrupted. Add sleeping to the end of the main function.

Comment: I (perhaps foolishly) assume the destructor of `ZThread` joins, but alas I'm probably wrong, as I'm utterly unfamiliar with that environment. I would expect to see `exit` in the output, but so far all we're told is one thing that *wasn't* printed; not what *was*.

Comment: I'm not that familiar too.

Comment: I'm not sure if the threads get interrupted because the program hangs. But sleeping or `std::cin.get()` at the end of `main()` helped. Thanks!